# Can not seem to get the jp2 delegate to work in ImageMagick on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, imagemagick

I have tried to install the library on both 14.04 and 15.10. Every time I type in `convert -version` the delegates do not contain jp2000. I have installed `libopenjpeg-dev` and `libjpeg-dev`

I have tried:

- Installing dependencies beforehand, then installing ImageMagick
- Installing dependencies after installing ImageMagick

But no cigar. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but what is a test to determine whether ImageMagick actually as jp2000 support, or whatever it is?

Comment: As per this top Google [search result](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=14213) what are the contents of your corresponding delegates.xml file? The jpg libraries may not be configured to update that file, if that's what needs to happen.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Normally, you can do "convert -version", it'll show all available delegates.

Answer (score -1):

Gimp opens jp2 files and you can read write and edit. Use version from ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp. This also gives you latest Gmic also.

I am using Gimp to print my own copies of some C19th text books. Project Gutenburg Scans for example.